# Unity 3d object to be shown after delay in the scene

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I have just learnt Unity3D and figured out drawing objects and creating scenes. I could not make objects appear after delay.
When the game starts I want objects appear after few seconds. I used waitforsec() but could not implement that.
Is there a simple way to activate object after delay since start of the game?

Comment: Include the code you have tried in your question, we can help you more then!

Comment: I usually don't answer this type of question unless code is provided but because it is an easy one, I changed my mind. Next time add your non working code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for 2 seconds then activate GameObject. You can change the 2 to any other number.

```
public GameObject gOBJ =null;

void Start()
{
 Invoke("showGameObject", 2);
}

void showGameObject()
{
 gOBJ.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: When I tried the above script, i get "compile error". What I did was I added new c# script to the game object as a new component and pasted the above script and get this error.

Comment: Even I kept the gameobject in the scene disabled or inactive and ran, now I dont get compile error but object never appears.

Comment: You are suppose to replace `gameObject` with the gameobject name you want to show.

Comment: Thanks so much. my object name was "bgs" when I put bgs.setactive(true), it says bg does not exist in the current context. I am so sorry.

Comment: I modified my answer with new code. Drag the gameObject you want to modify to the Script slot "GOBJ" in the Editor then run it. If that doesn't work, go to the Unity website and start learning. http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting